# Combine Eclipse PDT and Aptanta plugin w/ JQuery in the SAME project

Tags: php, jquery, eclipse, aptana, eclipse-pdt

I just got an opportunity to do a little more learning about web developing with PHP and trying to learn some JQuery too. I really enjoy using Eclipse + PDT over other IDEs that I have tried and the PDT library seems to really stand out among other PHP tools, IMO. But unfortunately it doesn't seem to have support for JavaScript and JQuery.

After doing hours of research and installing Aptana Studio as well as Aptana Eclipse plugin I was able to make the JQuery support (code assist) work by including the sdocml file into the project as dscribed [here](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries).

But it only seems to work if I create a project based on Aptanta's template, but in that case the original PDT support doesn't work. And the same thing happens vice verse with the JQuery support if I create a project based on PDT template, in which case the JQuery code assist doesn't work.

Is there a way to combine the two types of projects into one and make both JQuery and PDT support work at the same time?

I also tried just to use the Aptana Studio 3, which now has PHP support, but I didn't like it as much as the Eclipse's PDT.

NetBeans also have support for both JQuery and PHP, but again, not quite as good as PDT+Aptana, IMO.

Visual Studio wouldn't work for me as I am using mostly Linux for these projects, and I am not a big fan of the VS (or .NET) anyways, so I haven't even tried those.

Answer (score 1):

I once (that time around Eclipse Ganymede) did it this way: Install the PDT and the Aptana Plugin and then used the javascript editor for .js files. It worked flawlessly, maybe that's still an option. IIRC it was possible to only install a portion of Aptana, so I only installed the js editor.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it appears that there is no way to install only a portion of the Aptana plugin at this time. Also, the Aptana editors do work in the PDT project, but the "code assist" feature doesn't seem to function properly. But thanks anyways - I just added a vote for at least trying to answer my question.

Comment: What you can always do is to use different perspectives as well. Should be no problem to run Aptana in Full and PDT in parallel. Probably this is not the ideal solution but general in eclipse things should not stand against each other by default.